# Convert string into integer inside array Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I have an array that shown from console.log(res) just like this:

```
res = ["117498","4734","9782","53196"]
```

> How supposed to do if i want to convert the format of my array become
>   like this:

```
res = [117498,4734,9782,53196]
```

I'm confusing using map. on angular, if there is the way with map, what map's library that i have to import in my component.ts

My Code:

```
public apiData;
ngOnInit() {

this.countryunitservice.getTicketCountryUnit().subscribe((res)=>{
  this.apiData = res;
  console.log(res);
})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map()` by passing `Number` function as callback. As from [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number):

> In a non-constructor context (i.e., without the `new` operator), `Number` can be used to perform a type conversion.

```js
const input = ["117498","4734","9782","53196"];

const output = input.map(Number);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: giving the error "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'." man @Mohammad Usman

Answer (score 1):

`map` is a method included in `ES6` if you're using babel to transpile your code into `ES5` than you can use directly else you can use polyfill or libraries like underscore or loadash

You can use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and implicit conversion.

```js
const input = ["117498","4734","9782","53196"];

const output = input.map(e=> +e);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: i've used "import { map } from 'lodash';" at the library, but still giving the error "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'." man @Code Maniac

Answer (score 1):

simply do,

```js
let result = ["117498","4734","9782","53196"].map(val => +val);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import any library for map. It is provided by javascript itself.

Based on your comments, it seems that the response is an object and not an array. So, use `Object.values(res).map(Number)`

If your response is an array, the following would do.

```js
const output = ["117498","4734","9782","53196"].map(x => Number(x));

console.log( output );
```

Comment: It still giving the error man "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'." @dileepkumar jami. I dont know what should i do then

Comment: are you trying to use the map() on the array or an object?. It seems  you are using it on a object and hence the error. Please show the code how you are using

Comment: hi @dileepkumar jami, i've attached my code, thats before i add the code as your suggestion. res is array contain string on each part

Comment: seems weird. what is typeof(res) returning? Can you please check and tell me?.  It would be better if you post your code on stackblitz

Comment: @aldi, I Could not find the CountryunitService file in your code. Please put all the files or show me the implementation of the service

Comment: Case closed man @dileepkumar jami, i tried this : this.temp = Object.values(res).map(val => +val);

Comment: @aldi, Object.vaues() is applied on an object but not array. It seems your response is an object and not an array and hence you could not use map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and parseInt function

```
let result = ["117498","4734","9782","53196"].map(val => parseInt(val));
```